# Best way to upload large videos to web service iOS

Tags: ios, video, upload

I want to upload video to web service.

```
 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

     NSURL *chosenMovie = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

     NSData *uploaddata=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:chosenMovie];

   // Here I’m uploading bytes info to my server.

}
```

But its taking long time to upload, let me know other available options for fast uploading.

Comment: you can alter the quality of the video and start uploading it so that it would take a short amount of time. Are you consider doing that?

Comment: Converting to Mp4 like this         AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]initWithAsset:avAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];